# Does the SQLite db count towards the app's memory limit?

Tags: android, sqlite, memory-limit

I have an app that stores lots of things in SQLite. Does this count towards the memory limit that apps have? (dependent on hardware this is between 16 and 32 mb).

What about the :in-memory: flag for opening a DB on android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database does not count against the memory limit since it's just a file. The :in-memory: flag, though, **does** count against the memory limit.

Comment: @Erdal, The documentation for the sqlite3_open function (takes a file name; optionally ":memory:" for a temporary, in-memory database).

Answer (score 1):

As iconiK says, there is no limit for the database. But the internal memory of the device where your code is running  is the limit, if your database grows until the maximum internal memory size, it will throws an exception when you will try to write some stuff in db.